# How to add name as show[xyz], show[abc], etc for multiple checkboxes in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hii...
I want multiple checkboxes to be displayed as  and so on...name="show[adgroups]", how can i do this using zend form code?? Please see below example how I wanted my output to be viewed:

```
<div class="fieldgrp"> 
<label for="show_instructions">Instructions</label> 
<div class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="show[instructions]" id="show_instructions" class="" value="instructions" checked="checked" /></div> 
</div> 
<div class="fieldgrp"> 
<label for="show_adgroups">Campaign/Ad-groups</label> 
<div class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="show[adgroups]" id="show_adgroups" class="" value="adgroups" checked="checked" /></div> 
</div> 
<div class="fieldgrp"> 
<label for="show_keywords">Keywords</label> 
<div class="field"><input type="checkbox" name="show[keywords]" id="show_keywords" class="" value="keywords" checked="checked" /></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: not a real question: please read the ZF manual, especially the Zend_Form manual.

Comment: any answer would be appreciated, thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you create your Multiple checkbox set.

```
    $element = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('foo', array(
    'multiOptions' => array(
        'foo' => 'Foo Option',
        'bar' => 'Bar Option',
        'baz' => 'Baz Option',
        'bat' => 'Bat Option',
    );
    ));

    $element->setValue(array('bar', 'bat'));
```

The `Foo Option` would be the name of the checkbox in that group, while `foo` is the value.  The array that is passed in containing `bar` and `bat` are options that will be checked.

If you want to boost your reputation score on SO, then you should accept some answers to your questions.

Comment: edited the post and added the code how I want the output...plz suggest for the same, thank you.

Comment: hey how to get different labels displayed for all options using multicheck, I tried all possibilities but did not achieve, plz suggest.

Comment: anyone can help me - how to get the display as the code I posted for multiple checkboxes using zend form...thanx